# Parse Oracle Exception Error Message in PHP

Tags: php, regex, oracle, parsing, exception

I am trying to print exception message which is returned from Oracle's `RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR` method.

I can show that exception message with

```
$exc->errorInfo[2]
```

However there are some texts in that message which are not supposed to be shown to end users.
Here is the sample exception message:

> OCIStmtExecute: ORA-20001: My error MESSAGE ORA-06512: at "MYDB.PACKAGE", line 78 ORA-06512: at line 1 (/tmp/pear/download/PDO_OCI-1.0/oci_statement.c:142)

Is there any better way other than parsing this text with `preg_replace()`?

If no, Could you suggest any pattern to use in regex.

I have this working but it is not ideal solution:

```
    $parse1 = explode('ORA-', $exc);
    $parse2 = explode(':', $parse1[1]);
    return $parse2[1];
```

Comment: Well can you show us the output which you are expecting

Comment: @Gaurav just My error MESSAGE

Answer (score 2):

I have a pattern that you may be able to use. It depends on how much you want to cut out from the error message.

---

`^.*?ORA-\d*:\s*([^,]*).*$`

This regex will yield the following

> My error MESSAGE ORA-06512: at "MYDB.PACKAGE"

---

`^.*?ORA-\d*:\s*([^:]*).*$`

This regex will yield the following

> My error MESSAGE ORA-06512

---

[Regex101 Example](http://regex101.com/r/lV5mB3)

Comment: My error MESSAGE can be anything. I cant use it as pattern for preg_match.

Comment: I need to know more information about these error messages if I am to make an accurate matching regex, what parts change? What parts are consistent?

Comment: Message will always be after OCIStmtExecute: ORA-20001: but 20001 may change.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
preg_match('~ORA-[0-9]+: \K.*?(?=ORA-[0-9]+:)~u', $str, $match);
echo $match[0];
```

Comment: I have no idea why this is not working for me. It is not working if I supply $str to this function, but it is working if I put my error message string inside quotes instead of $str

Comment: @jCloud: of course `$str` represents your error message string!

Comment: I know. That is what I am talking about. I have never seen anything like this before. Look: if I use preg_match('~ORA-[0-9]+: \K.*?(?=ORA-[0-9]+:)~', $str, $match); It is not working. I am giving my error to $str. But If I use preg_match('~ORA-[0-9]+: \K.*?(?=ORA-[0-9]+:)~', 'OCIStmtExecute: ORA-20001: My error MESSAGE ORA-06512: at "MYDB.PACKAGE", line 78 ORA-06512: at line 1 (/tmp/pear/download/PDO_OCI-1.0/oci_statement.c:142)', $match); it works, but I need $str to be dynamic. Did you get? If it is dynamic (from variable) it fails,

Comment: if it is static (I put text manually in place of $str ) it works

Comment: Try to use another variable name than `$str`.

Comment: it does not matter. I have used $exc. Possibly it may be due to encoding. My messages are Russian.

Comment: If I var_dump I am getting OCIStmtExecute: ORA-20001: Ð’Ñ‹ Ð½Ðµ Ð¼Ð¾Ð¶ÐµÑ‚Ðµ ÑƒÑÑ‚Ð°Ð½Ð¾Ð²Ð¸Ñ‚ÑŒ ÑƒÑÐ»ÑƒÐ³Ñƒ Ñ€ÐµÐ·ÐµÑ€Ð²Ð¸Ñ€Ð¾Ð²Ð°Ð½Ð¸Ðµ Ñ‚Ð°Ðº ÐºÐ°Ðº Ð¼ÐµÑÑÑ† ÑƒÐ¶Ðµ Ð½Ð°Ñ‡Ð¸Ð½Ð°ÐµÑ‚ÑÑ Ñ‡ÐµÑ€ÐµÐ· 16 Ð´Ð½ÐµÐ¹ ORA-06512: at "DB.PACKAGE", line 78 ORA-06512: at line 1 (/tmp/pear/download/PDO_OCI-1.0/oci_statement.c:142)

Comment: @jCloud: Ok, in this case, try to add the u modifier, see my edit.

Comment: It did not work. Now I have to use my own method, which is exploding twice: 1st by ORA- and then by :

Comment: Thanks for all your support